# Best tool for visualizing results of test runs and integrating with Jenkins

Tags: python, automation, user-interface, reporting, jenkins

I have created a python tool to run regression tests that use FIX messages and compare the expected and actual FIX responses. I want to integrate this python tool with Jenkins as I want to automate regression testing. I would love to visualize the results from these test runs and I wanted suggestions on which tool to use. I have looked up Cucumber UI but the problem is that my tests are not in the BDD Gherkin format. Cucumber uses the BDD format to generate a JSON and/or an HTML report after tests are run. I could manually build the JSON file to get the HTML report but I cannot find the JSON spec for Cucumber UI.

Is there a tool that visualizes test results which can be integrated with Jenkins? For example I could create a JSON/XML file and supply it to that tool which would then generate a nice graphical representation of the data that was fed. This would greatly benefit any person analyzing the results and help in figuring out why tests failed.

Thanks in advance!